# Having trouble with getting URL config to work

Tags: python, django

I have an app, which I want to be the root of the website. So, I included the following urlpattern in my main urls.py like so:

```
(r'^$', include('search.urls')),
```

In my search `urls.py`, I have it set up in the following way:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('search.views',
    (r'^$', 'index'),
    (r'^results/$', 'results'),
)
```

The index urlpattern works, it goes to the index view, but the results urlpattern does not work. I get the following error when I try to access results:

```
Using the URLconf defined in textbook.urls, Django tried these URL patterns, in this order:

   1. ^books/
   2. ^$
   3. ^admin/
   4. ^static/(?P.*)$

The current URL, results/, didn't match any of these.
```

Edit: 
main `urls.py`:

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^books/', include('books.urls')),
    (r'^$', include('search.urls')),
    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),
    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
)
```

Comment: Please show the rest of your main urls.py.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try this(put the searchurl include at the end and remove the $):

```
urlpatterns = patterns('',
    (r'^books/', include('books.urls')),

    (r'^admin/', include(admin.site.urls)),


    (r'^static/(?P<path>.*)$', 'django.views.static.serve', {'document_root': settings.MEDIA_ROOT}),
    (r'^', include('search.urls')),
)
```

The reason for this is that the search  urls will only be included if your path matches ^$, this means that only the / url will match this pattern since $ marks the end of the pattern. The last line of my urlconf says: forward everything else to the search urlconf (notice the absence of $). Note, anything you place after this line will never be matched, since this line matches anything.